# Linux Virtual Interface “missing” pair?

Tags: linux, networking, amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes

- The Q may be specific to AWS EKS CNI/AWS EC2/AWS VPC Networking
- The Q may be specific to Docker networking

We have an AWS Elastic Kubernetes cluster running with a WorkerNode.
On this WorkerNode, we have a Pod running with an IP `10.22.55.231` assigned to it which is a part of the AWS VPC where this WorkerNode is living.

I'm wondering, how a packet will reach this Pod via Linux Network namespaces and interfaces.

So:

1. when I'm issuing a request to an AWS LoadBlancer, it will send a packet to an EC2's TCP port, let's say 30100 on the `eth0` interface
2. `ipfilter` on the EC2 will capture this packet and will send it over `iptables` tables and chains of the Host
3. it will reach the `nat` table and `PREPOUTING` chain, where will be captured by the `KUBE-SERVICES` chain
4. will reach the `KUBE-NODEPORTS` chain and will be sent to the `KUBE-SEP-xxx` chain
5. `KUBE-SEP-xxx` will send a client's packet to the `10.22.55.231` IP, which is the Secondary private IPv4 address of the AWS EC2

On the WorkerNode/EC2 in its routes `10.22.55.231` will be sent to the `enif8b7efe9956` interface:

```
[root@ip-10-22-50-163 ec2-user]# route -n | grep 10.22.55.231
10.22.55.231    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 enif8b7efe9956
```

Which is the `veth` interface from the Namespace with ID 6:

```
12: enif8b7efe9956@if3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9001 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 5a:ba:fe:22:92:aa brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 6
```

From everything I remember and googled, its second part of the `enia742601a852@if3` name, **if3**, specifies its second peer, where traffic is sent when it's coming to the `enia742601a852`.

But if I'm checking the `@if3` interface - it's the `eth1`:

```
[root@ip-10-22-50-163 ec2-user]# ip a s eth1
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9001 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0a:39:42:17:73:4c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.22.62.78/20 brd 10.22.63.255 scope global eth1
```

Why so? How this is going to be working? The packet will go again via `iptables`' `nat` and `PREROUTING`? It has to be sent via some Docker interfaces, isn't it?

The `link-netnsid 6` is used by our Kubernetes Pod/Docker container, and IP `10.22.55.231` mapped to this Namespace:

```
[root@ip-10-22-50-163 ec2-user]# nsenter -t 7114 -n ip a s
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth0@if12: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9001 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 32:62:fe:9e:7a:b5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 10.22.55.231/32 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Completely lost in here.

Comment: To shed some light, answers of mine on UL SE: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/441876/how-to-find-the-network-namespace-of-a-veth-peer-ifindex/441898#441898 , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444892/what-does-if1if2-mean-in-interface-name-in-output-of-ip-address-command-on/444911#444911 . The link-nsid means the @ifXX is in an other namespace. This link-netnsid is relative to the current namespace. Its value is not unique. Routing isn't done by iptables but by the routing stack. iptables can indirectly alter the routing behaviour eg when doing NAT.

Comment: So you got the information: **12**: enif8b7efe9956@ **if3** <----> **3**: eth0@ **if12**